# Unity transform.position and AddForce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. In Unity, how can I bring an object to the direction the character is facing every time?
   I tried this, but it always brings it to the right.I'm working with 2D.

   ```
   GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    tempItem.transform.position = player.transform.position + player.transform.right * 2f;
   ```
2. Additionally, after reaching this position, I want to apply a certain amount of force, but it won't be a continuous force; I just want it to push a specific amount. By the way, the gravity value in my game is set to 0.

I tried this, but the force is always applying, and it doesn't stop.

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(.2f, .3f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: if you dont have resistance or gravity or something why would it stop?

Comment: I was thinking of adding force to make it look like the player is throwing the item. It wouldn't make sense if the item I throw keeps moving forward, would it?

Comment: You seem to be failing to grasp that an item with no resistence or other effects  such as gravity upon it will keep travelling..

Comment: Wouldn't it stop if the same force acted in the opposite direction after some time?

Comment: as long as the item is flat and has no spin etc. probably but it could also bounce

Comment: Could I represent the item as if it's leaving the character using a different approach?